# How to resolve error 2042 for vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to do a vlookup function with VBA. However, it keeps ending up as 0 due to Error 2042. Did I do anything wrong with the coding? It keeps having error 2042.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
y = 2
For x = 17 To 21
    a = TextBox1.Value
    z = Application.vlookup(a, Sheet7.Range("A:F"), y, False)
    If Not IsError(z) Then
        Sheet1.Cells(42, x).Value = z
    Else
        Sheet1.Cells(42, x).Value = 0
    End If
    y = y + 1
Next x
```

Comment: Error 2042 means that your VLOOKUP is returning #N/A which generally means that whatever is in variable a is not in the lookup range.

Comment: a is supposed to be a year, am I supposed to set as a integer or string?

Comment: Step through your program and see what `a` and `y` are at the point of failure. That will give you an idea of what you have done wrong.